# How can I implement Redux in React correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've started to learn Redux with React, I got stuck in a part of my project which is a movies store that when the user chooses the number of tickets and clicks on add to cart I want to update the quantity and add the movie to the bag.

I implemented some redux in my code but the functionalities are not working?

What do you think?

<-- Constant-->

```
 export const ActionsTypes = {
     SET_MOVIES : "SET_MOVIES",
     GET_MOVIE : "GET_MOVIE", 
     REMOVE_MOVIE : "REMOVE_MOVIE",
     QUANTITY: "QUANTITY",
     ADD_PRODUCT : "ADD_PRODUCT",
 }
```

<-- My Actions -->

```
import {ActionsTypes} from "../Constants/ActionsTypes";


// create actions functions
export const setMovies = (movies)=> {
    return {
        type : ActionsTypes.SET_MOVIES,
        payload : movies,
    }
}


export const getMovie = (movie) => {
    return {
        type : ActionsTypes.GET_MOVIE,
        payload: movie,
    }

}

export const removeMovie = () => {
    return {
        type : ActionsTypes.REMOVE_MOVIE,
    }
}


export const AddProduct = (singleMovie) => {
    return {
        type : ActionsTypes.ADD_PRODUCT,
        payload: singleMovie,
    }
}
```

<-- Reducers --->

```
import { ActionsTypes } from "../Constants/ActionsTypes";

    const initialState = {
        movies: [],
        quantity :0,
    };
    
    
    // Reducers function takes two arguments state, action
    
    //Movies Reducers
    export const setMoviesReducers = (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case ActionsTypes.SET_MOVIES:
                return {...state, movies: action.payload }
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    
    // single Movies Reducers
    export const GetMovieDetailsReducers = (state={}, action) => {
        switch(action.type) {
            case ActionsTypes.GET_MOVIE : 
                return {...state, ...action.payload}
            case ActionsTypes.REMOVE_MOVIE : 
                return {};
            default : 
                return state;
        }
        
    }
    
    // Add to card and Quatity reducers
    export const AddMovieToCart = (state = initialState, action) => {
            switch (action.type) {
                case ActionsTypes.ADD_PRODUCT :
                    return {...state, quantity: state.quantity+1, products:[...state.products,action.payload]};
                default : 
                    return state;
            }
    
    }
```

<-- Combine reducers-->

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import { setMoviesReducers, GetMovieDetailsReducers, AddMovieToCart} from "./MoviesReducers";


export const reducers = combineReducers({
    allMovies : setMoviesReducers,
    movie : GetMovieDetailsReducers,
    addToCart : AddMovieToCart,
});
```

<-- Movie details component-->

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { Add, Remove } from '@material-ui/icons';
import './MovieDetails.css';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams  } from 'react-router';
import { getMovie, removeMovie, AddProduct} from '../../Redux/Actions/Actions';

import axios from 'axios';

const MovieDetails = () => {
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)
    const singleMovie = useSelector((state)=> state.movie);
    const addToCardProduct = useSelector((state)=> state.addToCart);
    console.log(addToCardProduct);

    const {title, poster_path, overview} = singleMovie;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let {movieId} = useParams();
    console.log(movieId);

    // Handle Quantity
    const handleQuantity = (type) => {
        if(type === "dec") {
            quantity > 1 && setQuantity(quantity - 1)
        } else {
            setQuantity(quantity + 1)
        }
    }

    // add to cart Handler
    const CartHandler = () => {
        dispatch(addToCardProduct);
    }


    // Get a single Product & Remove product
    useEffect(()=> {
        try {
            const getSingleMovie = async () => {
                const request = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId});
                const response = await request.data;
                dispatch(getMovie(response))
            }

            getSingleMovie();

        } catch(error) {
            console.log(`ERROR : ${error}`)
        }

        //Clean up
        return () => {
            dispatch(removeMovie());
        }
            
    }, [movieId])


    return (
        <section className="movieDetails_container">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="img-container">
                    <img src={`${ImgPath}` + poster_path} alt={title}/>
                </div>

                <div className="info-container">
                    <h1>{title}</h1>
                    <p>{overview}</p>
                    <div className="quantity-container">
                        <Remove className="quantity-icon" onClick={()=> handleQuantity("dec")}/>
                        <span className="amount">{quantity}</span>
                        <Add className="quantity-icon" onClick={()=> handleQuantity("incr")}/>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn-add" onClick={CartHandler} >Add To Cart</button>
                </div>
                
            </div> 
        </section>
    )
}

export default MovieDetails
```

<---Navbar where I have my bag icon and where I want to show the quantity-->

```
import React from 'react'
import './Navbar.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Badge } from '@material-ui/core';
import { LocalMall } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Navbar = () => {
    const quantityBag = useSelector((state)=> state.quantity);
    return (
        <nav className="navBar-section">
            <Link to="/">
                <div className="logo-container">
                    <img className="logo" src="./Pictures/warner-bros.png" alt="Logo"/>
                </div>
            </Link>

            <Badge badgeContent={0} color="primary">
                 <LocalMall className="icon-bag" />
            </Badge>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: In which point you are facing issue?

Comment: Please checkout redux/toolkit, the way you're using is old school.

Comment: Abu Sufian The problem that I'm facing is when I click on the button to add the quantity selected and movie to the bag is giving me an error